# List of all available nmap script arguments

Tags: nmap, nse

I need to do a scan, for example with ***http-sql-injection.nse***
nmap script.

I already know that I should use `--script-args` to set arguments, but my question is not about it.

How can I look **on the whole pack of arguments**, that this script (or any of nmap's scripts) can take?

Comment: what about The online NSE Documentation Portal https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ftp-anon.html ?

Comment: Much less official, but you can ask Nhelp in #nmap on Freenode IRC for information about a script, e.g. `?usage http-sql-injection` or `Nhelp args http-sql-injection`

Comment: Yes, you are right about the Nmap online documentation, there is a lot of useful information about the scripts arguments, but it's not the same I asked above. I hoped to find the way of getting arguments avoid going to the Nmap site. But with taking into consideration all answers here I find out that the online documentation is the best provider of needed information.

Answer (score 6):

Accordly with the [nmap documentation](https://nmap.org/book/nse-usage.html) in "Example 9.2. script help", the nmap's parameter that displays help about the script is:

```
nmap --script-help <filename.nse>
```

Namely:

```
nmap --script-help http-sql-injection.nse
```

If you look at [NSE documentation](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-10/whitepapers/Vaskovitch/BlackHat-USA-2010-Fyodor-Fifield-NMAP-Scripting-Engine-wp.pdf) written by own Nmap's creator:

> **3.1. description Field**
>
> The description field describes what a script is testing for and any importantnotes the user should beaware of.
>   Depending on script complexity, the description may vary from a few
>   sentences to a few paragraphs. The first paragraph should be a brief
>   synopsis of the script function suitable for stand-alone presentation
>   to the user. Further paragraphs may provide much more script detail.

Fyodor explain that the "description" field is used to describe everything about the complexity that the script itself might have. So, go ahead and look deeper into how the script was made:

```
 $ vi /usr/share/nmap/scripts/http-sql-injection.nse
```

...

```
 11 description = [[
 12 Spiders an HTTP server looking for URLs containing queries vulnerable to an SQL
 13 injection attack. It also extracts forms from found websites and tries to identify
 14 fields that are vulnerable.
 15 
 16 The script spiders an HTTP server looking for URLs containing queries. It then
 17 proceeds to combine crafted SQL commands with susceptible URLs in order to
 18 obtain errors. The errors are analysed to see if the URL is vulnerable to
 19 attack. This uses the most basic form of SQL injection but anything more
 20 complicated is better suited to a standalone tool.
 21 
 22 We may not have access to the target web server's true hostname, which can prevent access to
 23 virtually hosted sites.
 24 ]]
```

This explain why the `http-sql-injection.nse` script do not shown "usage options" whether that's what you expected to see.

---

The NSE scripts has a tradition to include "usage options" inside a comments. Such thing that was documented on the section "**8.1 The Head**":

> Next comes NSEDoc information. This script is missing the common
>   @usage and @args tags since it is so simple, but it does have an
>   NSEDoc @output tag:
>
> ```
> ---
> --@output
> -- 21/tcp   open     ftp       ProFTPD 1.3.1
> -- |_ auth-owners: nobody
> -- 22/tcp   open     ssh       OpenSSH 4.3p2 Debian 9etch2 (protocol 2.0)
> -- |_ auth-owners: root
> -- 25/tcp   open     smtp      Postfix smtpd
> -- |_ auth-owners: postfix
> -- 80/tcp   open     http      Apache httpd 2.0.61 ((Unix) PHP/4.4.7 ...)
> -- |_ auth-owners: dhapache
> -- 113/tcp  open     auth?
> -- |_ auth-owners: nobody
> -- 587/tcp  open     submission Postfix smtpd
> -- |_ auth-owners: postfix
> -- 5666/tcp open     unknown
> -- |_ auth-owners: root
> ```

Since the documentation does not explicitly show the use of "@usage", look yourself in `/usr/share/nmap/scripts/`:

```
$ grep -iR -A5 "@usage" /usr/share/nmap/scripts/  
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/ajp-brute.nse:-- @usage
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/ajp-brute.nse--- nmap -p 8009 <ip> --script ajp-brute
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/ajp-brute.nse---
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/ajp-brute.nse--- @output
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/ajp-brute.nse--- PORT     STATE SERVICE
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/ajp-brute.nse--- 8009/tcp open  ajp13
...
```

Answer (score 3):

First I use `locate nse | grep scripts` to list all the scripts

I simply `cat` and `grep` out the args for whatever script i want to use:

`cat /usr/share/nmap/scripts/whatever-script.nse | grep args`

This should show you all the arguments available for the specific script.